# Data visualization components to show structure of RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, data-visualization

I tried to find the best data visualization component for a Rails app, but I found only a few possibilities. The best component what I found is Highchart organisation graph(https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart), but I need something different, because I need this component to show the 'organization' of an app, and I need connections in the same row  (some models have a many-to-many association with the same model tables). Have you got any idea for a simple and pretty solution?

I tried Highchart rails, fusioncharts and more other charts, but I have got the same problem.

I expect a graph that can visualize connections in the same row.

Comment: Can you post a diagram of how do you want it?

Answer (score 0):

One option for this sort of diagramming is yEd, which has versions for lots of languages [including HTML](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles-for-html). It specialises in network, relationship and organisation diagrams, which should be much more relevant for you than libraries like Highcharts, which are designed for charting data.